# Issue with cosine similarity returning results over 1, even np.clip() did not work

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I have made a simple recommender system to act as a code base for my dissertation, I am using cosine similarity on a randomly generated dataset. however the results of the cosine similarity are over 1 and i cant seem to figure out how and why its happening

the code in question is:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def generate_random_data(n_users=50, n_items=50):
    users = [f'User{i}' for i in range(1, n_users + 1)]
    items = [f'Item{i}' for i in range(1, n_items + 1)]

    data = {
        'User': [],
        'Item': [],
        'Rating': []
    }

    for user in users:
        for item in items:
            if random.random() < 0.8:  # 80% chance of a user rating an item
                rating = random.randint(1, 5)  # Generate a random rating between 1 and 5
                data['User'].append(user)
                data['Item'].append(item)
                data['Rating'].append(rating)

    return data

data = generate_random_data()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
user_item_matrix = df.pivot_table(index='User', columns='Item', values='Rating').fillna(0)

# Calculate user-user cosine similarity
user_similarity = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(user_item_matrix), index=user_item_matrix.index, columns=user_item_matrix.index)

def get_recommendations(user, user_similarity, user_item_matrix, n_recommendations=2):
    if user not in user_similarity.index:
        return None

    # Calculate the weighted ratings using similarity scores
    weighted_ratings = (user_similarity.loc[user].values[:, np.newaxis] * user_item_matrix).sum(axis=0) / user_similarity.loc[user].abs().sum()

    # Convert the weighted ratings into a Series and set the index as the item names
    weighted_ratings = pd.Series(weighted_ratings, index=user_item_matrix.columns)

    # Sort the items based on the weighted ratings and filter out the items the user has already rated
    recommendations = weighted_ratings[user_item_matrix.loc[user] == 0].sort_values(ascending=False)

    # Return the top n_recommendations
    return recommendations.head(n_recommendations)

user = 'User1'
recommendations = get_recommendations(user, user_similarity, user_item_matrix)
print(f"Recommendations for {user}:")
for item, score in recommendations.items():
    print(f"{item}: {score}")
```

I'm relatively new to this side of mathematics in coding, so any help would be very much appreciated. i have taken out most of the tkinter stuff and some other functions with regards to loading in and exporting data sets.

Comment: cosine similarity return outputs in range(-1, 1). Try to cast your input to double first to check if this some overflow problem. If you could provide the inputs which causes this problem, it would better for us, so that we can help you.

Comment: Please make a small example that anyone can run, omitting all the irrelevant Tk stuff.

Comment: @MattHall i've edited the code to a non-tkinter version, hopefully this helps you